# Whats the issue with my implementation of SPSA(simultaneous perturbation stochastic approximation optimizer)?

Tags: python, optimization, stochastic

Here is my attempt to implement the SPSA optimization for the polynomial x^4 - x^2.  I recgonize my code only works for 1 dimension, but it seems to not be working at all. Also I recognize that SPSA is typically used when you dont have the function you want to minimize; it comes from measurements that contain noise like for example robot motion.Could it be perhaps that I am not using the np.random.binomial in the correct way? I used the pseudocode from this website https://www.jhuapl.edu/SPSA/PDF-SPSA/Matlab-SPSA_Alg.pdf to try and implement it. Sorry for the blocky code I am not used to stackoverflow. Please feel free to make other recommendations of how I can improve it. Thanks for your time.

```
import numpy as np
```

`def SPSA(alpha,gamma,lowa,A,c,iterations,theta):`

`dimension=len(theta)`

```
ppar = [1,0, -1, 0, 0]

p = np.poly1d(ppar)

# declare vector function quantities
gradient=np.zeros(dimension)
delta=np.zeros(dimension)
delta=np.random.binomial(3,.4, dimension)
if delta==0:
    print('error delta')
else:
    print('this is our delta')
    print(delta)
# simple for loop implementation as variables iterate
    i=0
    while i<=iterations:
        ak=lowa/np.power(i+1+A,alpha)
        ck=c/np.power(i+1,gamma)
        thetaplus=theta+ck*delta
        thetaminus=theta-ck*delta
        yplus=p(thetaplus)
        yminus=p(thetaminus)
        gradient=yplus-yminus/(2*ck*delta)
        theta=theta-ak*gradient
        print('graident, theta and F(theta)')
        return gradient,theta, p(theta)
        i+=1
        if gradient==0:
            print('gradient is zero')`
```

Answer (score 0):

> I recgonize my code only works for 1 dimension, but it seems to not be working at all.

The reason for this must be the unconditional `return gradient,theta, p(theta)`, which always exits in the first iteration. Perhaps you rather meant to write `print(…)` here and the `return …` at the end of the function.